# org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E: Property or field 'xxxxx' cannot be found on null

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to write a simple controller that will `POST` data from an HTML form to some REST endpoint.

Here's what my controller looks like:

```
package com.integration.common.controller;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;


@Controller
public class WebController {

@GetMapping("/form")
public String form(Model model){
    model.addAttribute("fieldProps",new FieldProperties());
    return "Form";
    }
@PostMapping("/form")
public String submit(@ModelAttribute FieldProperties fieldProps){
    return "Result";
    }
}
```

My model:

```
package com.integration.common.controller;

public class FieldProperties {
    private String owner;
    private String storyName;


    public String getOwner() {
        return owner;
    }

    public String getStoryName() {
        return storyName;
    }

    public void setOwner(String owner) {
        this.owner = owner;
    }

    public void setStoryName(String storyName) {
        this.storyName = storyName;
    }
}
```

And finally, my form:

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/form}" th:object="${fieldProps}" method="post" >
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="owner">Owner</label>
        <input type="text" id="owner" th:field="*{owner}" class="form-control"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="storyName">Name of Story</label>
        <input type="text" id="storyName" th:field="*{storyName}" class="form-control"/>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

I understand how the flow works, but for some reason I'm still getting this exception. Do I need to somehow incorporate the `@Autowired` flag into my code? I'm closely following this tutorial: https://spring.io/guides/gs/handling-form-submission/

Comment: Can you please share the exception which you are getting? Check complete code at https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-handling-form-submission.git

Comment: `Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "fieldProperties.owner" (Result:8)] with root cause`

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of passing model attributes from one view to another view.

a. Your FieldProperties class variable name should be same as "fieldProperties" instead of "fieldProps" and change html to refer to "fieldProperties".

```
@Controller
public class WebController {

    @GetMapping("/form")
    public String form(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("fieldProperties", new FieldProperties());
        return "Form";
    }

    @PostMapping("/form")
    public String submit(@ModelAttribute FieldProperties fieldProperties) {

        return "resultForm";
    }
}
```

b. If you don't want to change to code at all the places by changing variable then change your post method to below, add one more parameter Model model in the method and add fieldProps again as attributes in the model

```
@PostMapping("/form")
    public String submit(@ModelAttribute FieldProperties fieldProps, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("fieldProps", fieldProps);
        return "resultForm";
    }
```